# Search for C++ OAI-PMH Library

Tags: c++, oai

Is there a library or something else which provides an [OAI-PMH API](http://www.openarchives.org/) for c++?

I need such a library, because i have to calculate the Hirsch-Index for some authors in [citeseerx](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/index) as homework and i don't want to grep all Information from the website.

If anybody has a hint where i can find that please tell me.

Thanks